# How to make an exe file from Netbeans java project to run in all system which don't having JVM?

Tags: java, exe, netbeans-7

I have created one webcam application using netbeans IDE and java. then i converted that project into .exe file using launch4j software. that .exe file is running only on the systems in which java is installed. otherwise it shows an error JVM finding error class file is not available.

I want to make .exe file which will run in all type of systems.

tell me some suggestion. I am waiting

Comment: You will need to include a JVM with your program. I don't know about  launch4j, but NetBeans can do that (at list 7.4 and 8.0). In the project properties choose "Deployment" and check the "Enable native packaging" option there.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a .exe which will run in all systems, if by that you mean running on Windows, Mac, Linux, et cetera. Java is only portable (without recompiling) because it has the JVM as a layer insulating it from the details of the machine and operating system.

It's possible to bundle the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) with your Java code and ship it that way; you'd build an installer the same way you do for other .exe programs. But you'd need a separate installer for each platform.

There are also compilers that produce native code (.exe files or their equivalent) from Java. Again, that means giving up portability and having a separate version for each platform... and trusting a compiler that probably hasn't been thru the Java compatibility certification. (Plus giving up hotspot optimization.)

Comment: i tried the exe file in my system executed successfully. but that same exe file is failed to run in my friend system thats also window. but the file exe shows an error like JVM class file not found. is it necessary to install JVM to run exe file which developed in java?

Comment: How did you produce that .exe file? It's probably just an installer, which would mean that, yes, you need a JRE to run the Java code it installs.

Comment: i used the launch4j software to make that exe file

Comment: Sounds like you need to look for other tools. I haven't used them so I don't have recommendations. IBM's Java-based products generally ship bundled with a JRE (partly for this reason, partly to avoid possible incompatibility if the system JRE is a different release level than the one needed by the code).

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a java application without JVM installed. That's for sure. Other than that ,do you have any questions?? :)

Comment: i have converted the jar file of that project into exe file. That exe file runs in my computer successfully. but i cant run that exe file in my friend system. even for the exe file JVM is necessary?

Comment: Yes. It is necessary , the exe file also interanlly using the JVM. As i said , it is impossible to run Java application without JVM. Can you run a software without installing operating system. This is also the same.

Comment: tnx buddy. but i want to run that application even in the systems in which java is not installed. Is there any other way to convert java netbeans application into exe file ?